# Read the checkbox value and convert it into pdf

Tags: php, jquery, tcpdf

Can anyone help me how to read the value from the checkbox to display it in a pdf.I am having a form with name,age,prefernce etc. I have a checkbox for preference. When user clicks on submit the entered or selected value as to display in a pdf.I have only problem with the checkbox. It reads on a single value from the form.It as to read multiple values from the checkbox.Please help me out as I m new to tcpdf. Here is my code.This code reads only the last selected value from the checkbox. Please help me out.

```
php code

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#Submit").click(function(){
           $('input[name=per]').click(function(){
    $('input[name=per]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', true);

});
    document.getElementById("Form").submit();
        });

    </script>


    <form name="Form" id="Form" method="POST" action="pdf/pdf.php">


        <input type="checkbox" name="per" value="bike">bike<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="per" value="car">Car<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="per" value="bus">bus<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="formType" id="formType" value="veh" />
            <input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" class="formButton" />
        </div>

        </form></div>


pdf code

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('S');
$pdf->SetTitle('S');
$pdf->SetSubject('S');
$pdf->SetKeywords('S');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}


    $per="";
    if($_REQUEST["formType"] == "veh") {
   foreach($_POST['per'] as $check) {
        echo $check; 
} 

}
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$db = "mun";
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db,$dbhandle) or die('cannot select db');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO sjbhsmun1 (Name, age, grade, city, email,mobile, cper, choice1,choice2,choice3) 
                VALUES('$Name','$age','$per') ") or die(mysql_error());

----------------
--------

<tr>

                                        <td width="40%" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Preferences</td>
                                        <td width="60%" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';

    $html .= $per;
</tr>
```

Comment: $per = $_REQUEST["per"];

Comment: It reads only a single value. It doesnt read multiple value from checkbox

Comment: Use name="per[]" instead of name="per" in HTML..

Comment: Its the same thing.It displays only 1 value

Answer (score 0):

Change your checkbox names from `per` to `per[]`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="per[]" value="bike">bike<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="per[]" value="car">Car<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="per[]" value="bus">bus<br/>
```

In your PDF code use this to get all values

```
if(isset($_POST['per'])){
    foreach($_POST['per'] as $check) {
        echo $check;
    }
}
```

This will display all of the selected boxes

Comment: It displays only 1 value in pdf.

Comment: shows error  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Use below Code:
`if(isset($_POST['per'])){
   foreach($_POST['per'] as $check) {
        echo $check; 
    echo "<br/>";
   }
}`

Comment: Add print_r($_POST) at the top of your file and see what values are returning. IF you don't select any of the checkboxes then this may be the reason for your error. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I m getting the same error  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() –

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" class="formButton" />
```

change this line to this

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" class="formButton" />
```

than try this code

```
if(isset($_POST['per'])){
    foreach($_POST['per'] as $check) {
        echo $check;
    }
}
```

and also as Pooshonk mention

```
<input type="checkbox" name="per[]" value="bike">bike<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="per[]" value="car">Car<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="per[]" value="bus">bus<br/>
```